# How do I call public functions in this jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I'm using the plugin Bootstrap Paginator: http://bootstrappaginator.org and on their site they say you can access public methods such as setOptions but they don't say how to do this. Probably because it's obvious for most people how to do it but not for me.

The init part looks like this: `$("#myDiv").bootstrapPaginator(options)` and somewhere else in my code I want to modify those options. I want to do something like `paginator.setOptions(myNewOptions)` but I'm not sure how the syntax is for calling these public functions.

Basically what I want to do is to initialize the bootstrap plugin and then call the setOptions function each time the page content is dynamically changed.

Comment: console.log(paginator) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call public methods

```
$("#myDiv").bootstrapPaginator('setOptions', myNewOptions)
```

or to call setOptions

```
$("#myDiv").bootstrapPaginator(myNewOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to call it directly but rather to call `$("#myDiv").bootstrapPaginator(options)` again. See http://bootstrappaginator.org/#set-options.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered here: http://bootstrappaginator.org/#set-options

So, to invoke `setOptions` yourself, `$("#element").bootstrapPaginator()` will do what you need, once `$("#element")` is initialized... otherwise it will initialize it and set options.